# No bean named 'loggingFilter' available error when deploying Spring Boot application in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security enabled. When I run it on IntelliJ it works fine and I am able to log in and use the application as expected. But when I try to deploy it on tomcat 8.5.x and 9.x I get the error **No bean named 'loggingFilter' available error when deploying the application in Tomcat**. Here is the complete log

```
08-Feb-2020 00:59:35.839 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 3 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
08-Feb-2020 00:59:39.959 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
08-Feb-2020 00:59:57.047 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [delegatingFilterProxy]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'loggingFilter' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1114)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:338)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:243)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:283)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4546)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5191)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1720)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:479)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
08-Feb-2020 00:59:57.052 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

If it helps, I use **logback.xml** file to show INFO logs

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    <javax.servlet-api.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>
    <jsp-api.version>2.2</jsp-api.version>
    <tiles-jsp.version>3.0.8</tiles-jsp.version>
    <json-simple.version>1.1</json-simple.version>
    <commons-fileupload.version>1.3.1</commons-fileupload.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.10.4</joda-time.version>
    <modelmapper.version>2.3.0</modelmapper.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.10</lombok.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.3</jackson.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.2.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <json.version>20190722</json.version>
    <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.4.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mssql-jdbc.version>7.4.1.jre11</mssql-jdbc.version>
    <hazelcast.version>3.12.6</hazelcast.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Core dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Other Core dependencies-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mssql-jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utilities-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-hibernate53</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you add the loggingFilter bean and pom xml please ? Have you deployed to standalone Tomcat before ? Could you just use spring boot with embedded tomcat as executable jar ? do you need to deploy as war with standalone tomcat ?

Comment: I do not have any specific `loggingFilter` defined in my app. The current version being deployed on Tomcat as a WAR file. I can use executable deploy as executable jar but that requires changes in the deployment process

Comment: Thanks. Would you know where loggingFilter is defined ? web.xml or some spring internal bean or some other third party library ? Also spring boot version in use.

Comment: @user2683814 No, I couldn't find any loggingFilter. This is a new spring boot project and we use Angular as frontend. So we do not have any web.xml file and I am using Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: @Jadda  Post your dependencies. Which versions do you use? Do you use `spring-boot-starter` dependency or `spring-boot-starter-logging` ? What you described means it works when deployed to embedded Tomcat (via `Run` in IntelliJ), but fails when you deploy you app to standalone servlet container => so it narrows the search of required dependency down

Comment: Have you followed the checklist needed for WAR deployment ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

Comment: @Drew Updated the post with dependencies

Comment: @user2683814 Yes, I did.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be  possible to provide mvce example possibly a github project ?

Comment: could you try to launch your app as jar? I think build spring boot as war to deploy in tomcat is the problem. Try this : `mvn clean package`. Then in target folder : `java -jar your-app.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this exception is straightforward – Spring Security looks for a bean named **loggingFilter**, and cannot find it. This bean is required by the main Spring Security Filter – the **DelegatingFilterProxy** – defined in the `web.xml`

DelegatingFilterProxy is a class in Spring's Web module. It provides features for making HTTP calls pass through filters before reaching the actual destination. With the help of DelegatingFilterProxy, a class implementing the javax.Servlet.Filter interface can be wired into the filter chain.

DelegatingFilterProxy also leverages invoking specific or multiple filters as per Request URI paths by providing the configuration in Spring's application context or in web.xml.

Therefore, you must have a custom filter class and a configuration associated with this class. Check it because there is something you didn't see.

```
@Component("loggingFilter")
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        LOGGER.info("Request Info : " + req);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

To register a custom filter using **Java settings**:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer 
  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected javax.servlet.Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        DelegatingFilterProxy delegateFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
        delegateFilterProxy.setTargetBeanName("loggingFilter");
        return new Filter[]{delegateFilterProxy};
    }
}
```

Custom filter using configuration in **web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>loggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

CustomFilter implements javax.Servlet.Filter. This class has a @Component annotation to register as Spring bean in the application context. This way, the DelegatingFilterProxy class can find our filter class while initializing the filter chain.

Note that the name of the Spring bean must be the same as the value in the filter-name provided during the registration of the custom filter in ApplicationInitializer class or in web.xml later because the DelegatingFilterProxy class will look for the filter bean with the exact same name in the application context.

If it can't find a bean with this name, it will raise an exception at application startup.

You can find more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-delegating-filter-proxy).

Something that you can also check is if it is an **incompatibility problem between version of Spring and java** that you use.

I hope it can help you and in the end find a solution.

Comment: Weird. I actually defined custom `loggingFilter` before creating this post, it didn't work. Probably because of the fact I was implementing the Spring Security filter instead of a Servlet filter. It works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your question you indicate that *"...When I run it on IntelliJ it works fine... But when I try to deploy it on tomcat 8.5.x and 9.x I get the error..."*

**Follow these steps to find the cause:**

**1)** Do a complete Project clean: maven clean update, Tomcat clean, and regenerate the war files. This will ensure that your war is the same on both tests.

**2)** If the problem persists look at ItelliJ server version and make sure you are using the same Tomcat version for deployment.

**3)** If none of these is the cause you may be trying to fetch the required files from a remote location. Do you have aditional war files in the Tomcat server? are they using the same version? are you able to manually deploy in a fresh Tomcat on your machine without the help of IntellJ?

**4)** If the Tomcat is exactly the same, the wars are exactly the same and the Host is exactly the same. the results should be exactly the same*. If this is not the case, one of the previous statements is false so double check.

*Java version, memory allocation, and Server options can also Affect the result, but most likely it's not the case here.

**After you find the cause you can apply the following to solve it:**

- If your cause is the War, compare it with the previous working version, and you will probably find to have added a Custom Filter while adding Spring Security.
- If your cause is Tomcat, you may have a few extra libraries in IntelliJ's which your out of the box tomcat does not have.
- And if you use aditional wars make sure to update them

For a detailed explanation of **DelegatingFilterProxy** and Custom Filters checkout **borchvm**'s awnser.